# Disable rating on RatingBar

Tags: android

I'm using a RatingBar and OnRatingBarChangeListener in my Code.
The user can the rating once and after this I set 
        `ratingBar.setEnabled(false)` .
I want to show the user advice that he can't rate anymore.
How can I achieve to set a Toast after the user touches the disabled RatingBar?

Anybody an idea?

greetings

Comment: @Br0thazS0ul answer is correct

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You could set the rating to isIndicator after the user makes his first change
You should prompt the user to make sure his change is exactly as he wished. It can get pretty difficult to rate when the property stepSize (how precise the rating is) is 0.5

```
//You could prompt the user using a dialog to confirm he is done rating

ratingBar.setIsIndicator(true);
```

That should leave the UI unchanged(no greyish blur) and prevent the user from making a change (just like setEnabled(false))

In XML Layout

```
android:isIndicator="true"
```

Hope it helped

Comment: ratingaddrate.setIsIndicator(true); the method will be called like this.

Comment: Whats wrong with the people behind the android framework . Why dont they have consistent apis .setEnabled should have been the standard way to do perform this operation in all the views.

Answer (score 36):

As @Br0therzS0ul noted, it's `isIndicator`.

Here's how in XMl:

```
android:isIndicator="true"
```

Answer (score 3):

The moment you disable the rating bar, you could make an invisble overlay that will display a toast when it's clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Set

> ratingbar.setIsIndicator(true)

Now set the onClick Listener of rating bar or any parent view and display a toast if you receive a click

Answer (score 0):

its very simple write in your onClick() method

```
if(ratingBar.getEnabled()){
    Toast.makeText(<>,<YOUR message>,<>);
{
```

Comment: OnClick() does not work on progressbar and there is no such method as getEnabled() in ratingbar .kindly check and update how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

After applying either style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall" or scaleX/scaleY the click interaction with RatingBar is disabled. This works for me. Hope this helps you!

```
<RatingBar
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:transformPivotX="0dp"
android:transformPivotY="0dp"
android:scaleX="0.8"
android:scaleY="0.8"
android:isIndicator="false"
android:numStars="5"
android:stepSize="0.5"/>
```

Just to add up, android:isIndicator="false" made the differece.